# How to find the x coordinate of

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How to determine the X coordinate of the red point if i know the Y coordinate and the angle between the origin and the point? Let's say that Y is 40 and the angle is 35 degrees. How to determine the X coordinate? Or in other words the length of the adjacent side in the formed triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: If $\theta$ is the angle, then

$$\tan{\theta} = \frac{Y}{X}$$

where $\tan$ is the [tangent function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html).